# prove a complex number is a real multiple of another complex number

Tags: real-analysis

I need to check that $(5+i)^4 (239-i)$ is a real positive multiple of $1+i.$ I did the division of both and can not find the result.
Do you have any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Comment: (5+1)=6 is a real number. Is there a typo in your expression?If not, conjugate must bu $A(239+i)$

Comment: Yes, there is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plan (I think) to prove or disprove that $(5 + i)^4(239 - i)=C(1+i)$ where $C$ is a real number. If you multiply out
$$(5 + i)^4(239 - i)= 114244+114244 i = 114244(1+i)$$
so the claim is true for a real $C=114244$.

Answer (score 2):

You probably got this question in the reversed direction, but just FYI, here's another approach:

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) that

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = 4\arctan\frac{1}{5} + \arctan\frac{-1}{239}$$

We can write these as complex numbers, where $\arg(re^{i\theta}) = \theta$:

$$\begin{align*} \arg(1 + i) &= 4\arg(5 + i) + \arg(239 - i) \\ \arg(1 + i) &= \arg((5 + i)^4(239 - i)) \\ 1 + i &= k(5 + i)^4(239 - i)\end{align*}$$

Where $k\in\mathbb{R}$, as desired.